# How to Generate a Unique, Shareable ID on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a situation where a user can generate a "table" where other players can join them, much like how the Jackbox party games generate an easy link players can type into their phones to join a game without making an account.

However, whereas Jackbox is somewhat web based and uses URLs, I am trying to do everything within Firebase since this is a one man project. Obviously, this will mean that every user must have the app, which is fine for my use-case. I realize Firebase objects can create their own unique IDs, but those are pretty long, and I am not sure how to shorten them into a user-friendly code while guaranteeing that the generated code will not be a duplicate.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to generate the ID server-side, and store a unique ID with each game session (or "table" as you call it). There's no way to guarantee uniqueness without checking the DB for the presence of the ID each time it's generated (or using a sufficiently long ID so as to *virtually* guarantee it, but that's antithetical to your business requirement)

Comment: That sounds like a good start for an answer @HEATH3N :-)